# Copy rich text with image to NSPasteboard and paste in Word

Tags: swift, macos

I want to set text and image to `NSPasteboard` by code, so then I can paste into Microsoft Word.

For now I think of a way is to organize an RTF object and set via:

```
let board = NSPasteboard.general
board.clearContents()
board.setData(data, forType: .rtf)
```

So I test by download a RTF file and process like this:

```
func test() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "cat", withExtension: "rtf")

    if url != nil {
        let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url!)

        if (data == nil) {
            print("data is null")
            return
        }
        print("data", data)

        let board = NSPasteboard.general
        board.clearContents()

        // still rtf image is lost.
        let rst = board.setData(data, forType: .rtf)
        if (!rst) {
            print("setData failed")
        }
    }
}
```

It works partly, but the image is lost. Only pasted the text.

How can I fix this issue. Or any other way to do this(copy both image and text to `NSPasteboard`).

The [test rtf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g3ypekg1hlt8t0i/cat.rtf?dl=0)

Some link I searched:

[trouble saving NSAttributedString, with image, to an RTF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370275/trouble-saving-nsattributedstring-with-image-to-an-rtf-file/29181130#29181130)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/documenttype/1532538-rtf/

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Tasks/RTFAndAttrStrings.html

Comment: How big is the data guy?

Comment: The right format is rtfd, by the way.

Comment: The data is very big, I forget the specific value, but it contains the image data. And I will try rtfd tomorrow.